# Problema al conectar endpoint de node js con fetch

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, express, fetch

resulta que estoy realizando un formulario que obtiene los datos del usuario y los almacena en la base de datos a través de un método post pero al momento de llamar la api del fetch me retorna un error como si no estuviera recibiendo los datos del body que se deben colocar

[image: Acá muestra el error en la consola]

[image: Acá me lanza el mensaje que creé en la instanciación de la tabla]

ya traté de convertir la clase que viene del front end a JSON.stringify pero aún así no me funciona, agradecería su ayuda ya que me encuentro atascado y no he podido almacenar los datos

esta es mi Api:

```
const url = `${basePath}/${apiVersion}/post-contact`;
const params = {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
}
console.log(params.body);

return fetch(url, params).then(response => {
    return response.json();
}).then(result => {
    return result
}).catch(err => {
    return err
})
```

acá la llamo en el front end

```
const {name, email, lastName, phone, reason} = inputs;
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-useless-escape
    const emailValid = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    const resultValidation = emailValid.test(email);
    
    if(!email || !name || !lastName || !phone || !reason){
        notification["warning"]({
            message: "Todos los campos son obligatorios."
        })
        
    }
    else{
        if(!resultValidation){
            notification["warning"]({
                message: "Verifique el correo."
            })
        }else{
            contactApi(inputs)
        }
    }
```

como pueden ver hice un console.log de la data que recibe la api y me la retorn como un Json (en la imágen aparece como si fuera una clase pero esa imágen la tomé antes), cómo información adicional la data que estoy tomando del front end se está guardando en un useState.
Si yo tomo los datos que aparecen en la consola y los pego en postman por el body, me registra exitosamente los datos pero en el api o en el front end no se guardan bien, ayuda!!!

Este es el código del controller

```
    const Contact = require('../models/contact');


function getContact(req, res){

    const contact = new Contact();
    const {name, lastName, email, phone, reason} = req.body;

    contact.name = name;
    contact.lastName = lastName;
    contact.email = email;
    contact.phone = phone;
    contact.reason = reason;

    
        contact.save((err, contacStored) => {
            if(err){
                res.status(500).send({code: 500, message: "El correo ya está en la base de datos."})
            }else{
                res.status(200).send({code: 200, message: "Se ha registrado correctamente, en breves nos comunicaremos con usted."})
            }
        })
    
    
}

module.exports = {
    getContact
}
```

este es el de la ruta

```
   const express = require('express');
const Contact = require('../controllers/contact');

const api = express.Router();

api.post("/post-contact", Contact.getContact);

module.exports = api;
```

Comment: Estas seguro de que tu back-end esta corriendo? No esta encontrando la ruta. Podrías mostrarnos el código del endpoint en el back-end?

Comment: Sí, está corriendo, ya comprobé con postman enviando un JSON y sí lo guarda

Comment: Ya coloqué el código del controlador y de la ruta

Comment: en qué parte defines `data`?

Comment: Es un useState que empieza con un objeto con name, lastName, email, phone y reason vacíos y los defino con un onChange en el form

Answer (score -2):

A mi me ha funcionado de la siguiente manera:

```
const params = {
    method: "POST",
    body: new URLSearchParams({
       data: 'tu data'
    })
}
```

Comment: Podrías editar tu respuesta y agregar por que este código soluciona el problema por favor? Así aumentarás su calidad, será mejor recibida y tanto el autor de la pregunta como quienes vean tu respuesta más adelante podrían aprender algo nuevo.